# How to model capacity (value and unit) in Domain Driven Design?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

If I have a `Tank` entity, would it be correct to have a `Capacity` value consisting of `Capacity.Value` and `Capacity.Unit`?

I would usually have Tank.CapacityValue and Tank.CapacityUnit, but I think this is not correct in a DDD scenario. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Sure, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: Side note: please try not to separate value and units - the chance of doing something like `1L+3Gal (=4L? 4Gal? )` is generally too high in such case. There are some well know cases of this like [Mars Orbiter](http://mars.jpl.nasa.gov/msp98/news/mco990930.html) - so consider not following footsteps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're after the `Quantity` pattern as described [here by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html):

> ... But using objects invites us to add new fundamental types whenever they add value, and having a specific type for dimensioned quantities adds quite a lot of value.

Comment: I prefer to call it Measure. There are many useful things you can do with them, e.g. Conversions, sanity checks when calculating with them, properly defining physical constants, etc.